# JavaFX Robot.getScreenCapture causing scene to not update prior

Tags: java, javafx

I have an options menu from which you can save the game and it should briefly close the menu and take a screenshot of the current game.
However, the menu does not close until after calling getScreenCapture even though it runs before causing the screenshot to always be of the settings menu.

(The screenshot itself is working it's just controlling what displays at the time of the screenshot)

!! Without the screenshot line it updates the scene immediately even though the scene change line comes before.

So far I have tried Thread.sleep but no length of time allows for the scene to update

//The initial call to save:

```
private void saveRoom() {
    program.changeState(previous);
    room.save();
}
```

//The changing of scenes: (State extends Scene)

```
public void changeState(State state) {
    currentState = state;
    stage.setScene(currentState);
    currentState.paintAll();
}
```

//How the game scene draws to screen:

```
@Override
public void paintAll() {
    ArrayList<Shape> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Furniture f : furniture) {
        f.paint(toAdd);
    }
    optionsButton.paint(toAdd);
    addFurnitureButton.paint(toAdd);

    root.getChildren().clear();
    root.getChildren().addAll(toAdd);
}
```

//How the options menu draws to screen (same as game):

```
@Override
public void paintAll() {
    ArrayList<Shape> toAdd = new ArrayList<>();
    
    toolsButton.paint(toAdd);
    saveButton.paint(toAdd);
    saveAndExitButton.paint(toAdd);
    exitButton.paint(toAdd);
    closeButton.paint(toAdd);
    
    root.getChildren().clear();
    root.getChildren().addAll(toAdd);
}
```

//The capture command:

```
robot.getScreenCapture(null, new Rectangle2D(x,y,x1,y1));
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. there are no methods paint/All in fx

Comment: When I say paintAll it is a custom abstract I method I use in my custome State class which extends Scene which is how I manage the displaying objects on the screen for each part of the application. I add all the shapes to an arraylist in order from back to front and then add them to the root group to display them; the methods are in the code above for both game and settings which do the same.

Answer (score -1):

Update: I am now using the Scene.snapshot command to take the screenshot instead and it does not cause the problem, but am still open to finding out how to go about using Robot to take a screenshot since unlike Scene.snapshot, it captures the whole screen rather than just the program which could come in handy in a future project.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.